# Uniform and Non-Uniform PPTs

Tags: computational-complexity-theory

While reading the paper

- 2020 - [Non-Malleable Codes for Bounded Polynomial Depth Tampering](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/776) by Dana Dachman-Soled and Ilan Komargodski and Rafael Pass

I stumbled upon the case in which it was necessary to state whether the authors were assuming uniform or non-uniform attackers. For what I know, non uniform PPT are basically a sequence of PPTs, so $\mathcal{A}=\{\mathcal{A}_1,\mathcal{A}_2,\dots,\mathcal{A}_n\}$, and on input $x$ of size $|x| = \lambda$, $\mathcal{A}_\lambda$ is called.
Why is this model "stronger" than the uniform one?
Couldn't ad attacker $\mathcal{A}$ just embed all the other attackers into its own description and invoke the suitable one?
Are there problems we know how to solve in the uniform model but not (if not with weaker guarantees) in the non-uniform model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a unary enumeration of all Turing machines, e.g. a machine $M$ is represented by $1^{\lambda_M}$ for some unique integer $\lambda_M$.
The halting problem is uncomputable, even in this "sparse" representation. But it is non-uniformly computable, as each Turing machine $M$ either halts or does not, and we can "hard-code" deciding this into each turing machine $A_{\lambda_M}$.

If we could "uniformly generate" the $A_i$'s, meaning efficiently generate them from the solely the description of $i$, you would be right. In the above example, you can't, as you don't know whether each Turing machine $M$ halts.

Comment: Another way to see that non-uniform algorithms can do things that uniform algorithms can't: there are uncountably many non-uniform algorithms but countably many uniform algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I was wondering if we know practical problems that become easier in the non-uniform model. Rephrasing, how can an encryption/commitment/signature... scheme offer a certain level of security when we assume uniform adversaries but lower levels of security against non-uniform adversaries, if we can build a uniform adversary hard-coding the others into its own description (and still have a polynomial description size)

Comment: @jacobi_matrix See section 4 of [another look at tightness 2](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/360.pdf) for some discussion of non-uniform hardness assumptions. It is worth mentioning that a somewhat related notion of "pre-processing" attacks (where one gets instance-specific advice) has a number of examples where they help (and can lead to practical attacks), for example the [logjam attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logjam_(computer_security)), or many problems in lattice-based cryptography (although most lattice cryptosystems generate fresh instances each time, limiting the danger of precomp

Comment: @jacobi_matrix the issue is that you can't build a uniform adversary hard-coding the others into its description, as generating an arbitrary $A_i$ may not be efficiently computable (or even computable at all, for example the "Sparse halting problem" non-uniform algorithm given in my answer). Moreover, you can't just "store" them all in the uniform adversary, as the uniform adversary would have too large of a description.

Comment: Perfect! The section that you linked and the logjam attack exemple really did the trick. The problem was that i thought (wrongly, obviously) that the advice string had to be the input size itself (eg. encoded in unary). Thanks again .